# How to get image.plist in android cocos2D

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

I am developing a game where i need .plist as in this line cache.addSpriteFrames("ninja.plist"); since i am new i dont know how to get .plist in cocos2d. Can any one help me how to get .plist for android cocos2d. Answers will be appreciated and it would be a great help because in google there is not much information about cocosd2D android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a texture packing software such as Texture Packer ; You can add your frames to the spritesheet and then it will generate the appropriate png and plist files.